# Daily new users Identity in Fabric plugin for Android - crashlytics

Tags: android, crashlytics, crashlytics-android, fabric.io

How does the daily new users active figure calculated?Does it mean that these users are the first timers?
Is there any documentation which explains these words like :

Monthly Active
Daily Active
Daily New
Crash-free Users
Total Sessions

Is there a way to know the smartphone models and Android versions of these *Active users?How?

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a reference point from Fabric's [documentation](https://docs.fabric.io/apple/answers/answers-metrics.html).

**Daily Active Users:**
The number of unique app installations across all devices that were active on a specific day. Note: Foreground activity must happen for a device to be active.

**Daily New Users:**
The number of new app installations across all devices on a given day. Deleting and reinstalling the app would create a new daily user. Updating versions of the app will not create a new daily user.

**Monthly Active Users:**
The number of unique app installations across all devices that were active over the trailing 30-day period. Note: Foreground activity must happen for a device to be active.

**Crash-Free Users:**
The percentage of daily active users that had a crash-free experience on a given day. Note: On Android or iOS, caught exceptions or logged errors are not considered crashes and are not included in this metric.

**Sessions:**
The total number of sessions across all app installations on a given day.

If you go to the "Audience" page from your app's dashboard on Fabric, you can see the devices and OS versions being used for the current day. If you click on the graph for a day in the past, then you will see the values from that day.

Comment: what does the "No occurrences within the custom range!" Means?

Comment: It means that no event, crash, etc was seen in the custom time range selected.